# Socket.IO chat application

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, variables, socket.io

I found a good chat application that I implemented on my site. Though, I noticed that I can change my username in the console cause it's just a variable in the front end. Now, the variable is an PHP variable from MySQL so I have no idea how to make it so people can't change their nicknames.. Any suggestions?

```
this.steamid    =   "<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']))echo $_SESSION['steamid']; ?>";
this.name       =   "<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']))echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>";
this.avatar     =   "<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']))echo $_SESSION['avatar']; ?>";
```

What I would do is to move those variables backend, but I don't know how to do it or if it's the most efficient thing to do.

If you need any more information to help me with this issue, please ask.

Comment: A seemingly simple question with a deeper and very complicated answer. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @apokryfos I have not tried anything actually, I've been googling around for answers, but don't find anything good. Though, I've read something about Javascript sanitization, but I don't find any good documentation about this. Do you know anything about sanitization that may help me with this issue?

Comment: First accept that you have no control over what the client can do with JavaScript. Once you've accepted that you just use the `$_SESSION` variables on the server side to verify who the user is.

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah, that's what's bugging me.. I can't seem to find a good way to do it..